# "An item with the same key has already been added" in dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a a problem in my C# code.
I keep getting an error "An item with the same key has already been added" and I tried various things suggested on the net, but I can't seem to get rid of it.
Can someone please help. 
I get the error on this line

```
ExistIncInsList.Add(WSIncInstOutput[Insrow][0], Int32.Parse(WSIncInstOutput[Insrow][1]));
```

below is the part of the code that involves this.

Karabo

```
Dictionary<string, int> ExistIncInsList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int Insrow = 2; Insrow < WSIncInstOutput.Count(); Insrow++)
{
    int existincWSInsID = Int32.Parse(WSIncInstOutput[Insrow][1]);
    if (!ExistIncInsList.ContainsKey(WSInsName))
    {
         ExistIncInsList.Add(WSIncInstOutput[Insrow][0], Int32.Parse(WSIncInstOutput[Insrow][1]));
    }
    if (MaxIncIndID < existincWSInsID)
    {
        MaxIncIndID = existincWSInsID;
        if (MaxIncIndID > MaxIndID)
        {
            MaxIndID = MaxIncIndID;
        } 
     }
}

if (ExistIncInsList.ContainsKey(WSInsName))
{
    WSInsID = ExistIncInsList[WSInsName];
}
else
{
    WSInsID = MaxIndID + 1;
    MaxIndID++;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Can you show a sample output? ...

Comment: can u please post some example dictionary items you wish to achieve using this code.

Comment: I've edited my question to show the part that triggers the error message.

Answer (score 11):

Check the correct key:

```
if (!ExistIncInsList.ContainsKey(WSIncInstOutput[Insrow][0]))
```

instead of:

```
if (!ExistIncInsList.ContainsKey(WSInsName))
```